# How to get parent node information in angular drag and drop lists

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have trying to create a environment where any person can drag, drop and  sort.
Person can drop card into any other card and also can drag out card from any card but to do this I will have to know the parent card information. I have looked all documentation but didn't find any option to get the card information in which a card is dropping in.

```
<ul dnd-list="containers"
dnd-allowed-types="['container']"
dnd-external-sources="true"
dnd-dragover="dragoverCallback(index, external, type, callback)"
dnd-drop="dropCallback(index, item, external, type)">
<li ng-repeat="container in containers"
    dnd-draggable="container"
    dnd-type="'container'"
    dnd-effect-allowed="copyMove"
    dnd-moved="containers.splice($index, 1)"
    dnd-callback="container"  id="{{container}}" ng-model="container">
    <div class="container-element box box-blue">
        <h3>Container (effects allowed: {{container.effectAllowed}})</h3>
        <ul dnd-list="container.items"
            dnd-allowed-types="['item']"
            dnd-horizontal-list="true"
            dnd-external-sources="true"
            dnd-effect-allowed="{{container.effectAllowed}}"
            dnd-dragover="dragoverCallback(index, external, type,callback)"

            dnd-drop="dropCallback(index, item, external, type)"
            dnd-inserted="logListEvent('inserted at', index, external, type)"
            class="itemlist">
            <li  ng-repeat="item in container.items"
                dnd-draggable="item"
                dnd-type="'item'"
                dnd-callback="item"
                dnd-effect-allowed="{{item.effectAllowed}}"
                dnd-dragstart="logEvent('Started to drag an item')"
                dnd-moved="container.items.splice($index, 1)"
                dnd-dragend="draged(event, dropEffect)" id="{{item}}" ng-model="item">
                {{item.label}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share a sample code for what you did and need help on it

Comment: please check and let me know if I can do something here

Answer (score 0):

It will be the best if you show your code.

I assume you're talking about communication between parent component to a child component.

You can do it with:

1. **Events**: $scope.broadcast (parent to bottom) or emit (child up) events.
2. **Bind to parent attribute** - read about the "bindToController" attribute in the directive definition object (being used when child is a element directive).

There are more methods like using $scope.$watch on a property or using a shared service but i would have stick with the 2 i mentioned above.

EDIT:
In your example, i see that you're using a 3rd party directive.

Not sure how you want to use the parent's data, but notice that for each "item" (the inner ng-repeat), **the "container" scope (his parent) is available**, you can access it directly in the markup, and pass it to the relevant attribute of the "item".

Comment: Please check now